# ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.sizeandtimebasedrollingpolicy not honoring maxfilesize given

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, rollingfileappender

ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.sizeandtimebasedrollingpolicy with 10MB size is not generating new file after the size limit reached to 10MB.
sometimes it roll file at 12912KB and sometimes it goes upto 17216KB and sometimes at 10780KB.

Why there is inconsistency in the file size?

I am trying to add logger to my spring boot application which will give log file of 10MB size and it will achieve the file once it reaches size >10MB which results in creating a achieved file of 10MB